# WebXR not working in Chrome 67 (With all XR flags enabled)

Tags: google-chrome, webvr

When I run the following command

`navigator.xr.requestDevice()`

in the console of chrome (Version 67.0.3396.62 (Official Build) (64-bit)) developer tools (after enabling **ALL** WebXR flags under chrome://flags and restarting the browser) I receive this error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: No devices found.
```

This sample code also didn't work...
https://github.com/immersive-web/webxr-samples/blob/master/xr-barebones.html

I tried this on a desktop and mobile Chrome browser.

Why is the WebXR API not working in Chrome 67?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Chrome Canary to use the WebXR api. It will not be available in stable for quite sometime.
Once you have Chrome Canary (the present version is: 69.0.3). You will have to enable `#webxr` and `#webxr-hit-test` flags.

Once you have that.
Goto this URL to test out the API and it should work for you.

```
https://immersive-web.github.io/webxr-samples/proposals/phone-ar.html
```

A lot of the older API's won't work now. So don't forget to take a look at the source code.

```
https://github.com/immersive-web/webxr-samples/blob/master/proposals/phone-ar.html
```